# jQuery Asual address keeps appending sites root folder

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, deep-linking

I have an MVC site located in several subfolders on a site for dev & stage:

- www.domain.com/site_dev/
- www.domain.com/site_stage/

It will eventually end up at the root of the site in production, but when testing my site in the subfolders jquery address appends the subfolder in the deep-linking like so:

- www.domain.com/site_dev#!**/site_dev/home/about**

I'm using ajax to load panels dynamically using the values in the deep linking, but my panels won't load because it's trying to call the controller **/site_dev/home/about** which does not exist.

How can I get it to not do this? I would like it to simply use:

- www.domain.com/site_dev#!**/home/about**

I don't want to hard code the values anywhere so it needs to be dynamic. I've searched all over, but maybe I'm not using the right keywords for what I'm looking to do. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: same here, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The problem is caused that jquery address thinks that `www.domain.com/site_dev/` is the root instead of www.domain.com. This will cause all url's to be loaded after `www.domain.com/site_dev#!/` You need to fix in the  init() of the plugin. Simply do

`$.address.state('/').init(function(event)`

Probably you had something similar to (this was my case):

`$.address.state($.address.baseURL()).init(function(event)`

or

`$.address.state('www.domain.com/site_dev').init(function(event)`

Comment: Thanks bicycle! I'll give it a shot next time I work on the site and if it works I'll mark your response as the answer. Appreciate you taking the time to respond!

Comment: Thanks @bicycle, I´ll also give a try on my current project. I hope I can soon mark it as the right answer.