# jQuery Address appends new deep link to existing deep link

Tags: jquery, pushstate, jquery-address

It's i think about the same issue [as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256638/jquery-asual-address-keeps-appending-sites-root-folder) but no solution there was given. 
If you directly enter a jQuery Address loaded website through a deep link `http://www.domain.com/deeplink1`and you would want to go to a next page by pressing a link, the next deep link is appended to the initial deep link `http://www.domain.com/deeplink1/deeplink2`.

How do I prevend this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was actually simple. [This post](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/issues/206) brought me up the idea (which is a bit ironic  actually since it's a post about jquery address competitor hehehe). I had at initialization the following set up

`$.address.state($.address.baseURL()).init(function(event)`

this caused the entry url to be the root domain. I now changed this to

`$.address.state('/').init(function(event)`

which causes the root (hostname) to be the entry domain. This solved the problem.